# PHP zend style URLs build

Tags: php

I have url for example http://www.website.com/page/parm1/one/parm2/two?me=you

I need this url like zend framwork, it should be splited and give me params like

```
'controller' => page
'parm1' => 'one'
'parm2' => 'two'
'me' => 'you'
```

how canI do it with **PHP**?

Answer (score 0):

You can't just do it with PHP alone You need to first look into [Apache mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/intro.html) and then start using `.htaccess`. Once you have it setup in your project you can just `explode($delimeter,$string)` the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` by delimeter `/` which will give you an array like you have expected. but If you also want the query params to work you just have to add more logic which i guess you'll figure it out :).